# Collect UDP(Gelf) messages and forward with TCP to logstash

Tags: networking, logging, docker, elastic-stack

I am looking a lightweight tool that receives UDP packages on some port (Docker Gelf-logs in my case), stores them internally and then forwards them with TCP in an efficient way (in my case to logstash from elastic stack). Ideally this application is already dockerized. Any suggestions?

Comment: Doesn't logstash already have a gelf input? Can you explain more about why you don't want to just go Docker gelf -> logstash or why that is not possible?

Comment: UDP is not reliable as packages might be lost. I would like to avoid that by having a lighweight service on localhost (localhost never looses packages if the receiver can manage the load) that forwards the messages with tcp to my logstash. I don't want to run logstash on each instance of the swarm because it consumes a lot of memory